# Український відповідник до слова "ажіотаж"

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова

Згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6) слово "ажіотаж" походить від французького "agiotage" та має значення: "спекулятивна гарячка на ринках, біржі, викликана несподіваним, різким, зазвичай штучно створеною зміною курсу коштовних паперів або цін на товари". В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/azhiotazh) також зустрічаємо це слово, де у нього є також ще й таке значення: "Велике збудження, хвилювання, боротьба інтересів навколо якої-небудь справи, питання".

Чи існує в українській мові якийсь відповідник, яким б можна було замінити це слово? На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bum) є переклад слова "Бум", яке вважається синонімом до слова "ажіотаж". Там даються такі варіанти: "гамір, "гармидер", "пекучка", "галас". Однак мені здається, що ці відповідники не завжди будуть доречними, адже якщо є термін попит ажіотажний, то невже можна сказати "гамірний" чи "голосливий попит"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

До даного Вами переліку можна додати подані до **ажіотаж** синоніми у [Словнику синонімів Л. Полюги](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=23&t=26):

> (**надмірне збудження) гарячка, лихоманка**.

Також можна сказати: [збудження, хвилювання](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/%D0%90/%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6).

Теоретично, можна сказати і **гарячковий попит** і **гамірний** ( і інше), однак, вважаю, що на даний момент така спроба в українській мові не "приживеться", оскільки [ажіотажний попит](http://www.megos.org.ua/marketynh.1.3.html) є одним із видів попиту, терміном, запозиченим маркетингом, який, на мою думку, покищо не "шукає" українських відповідників.